# Is there a way to autofill all class / widget properties in vs code and create some shortcut for that?

Tags: flutter, dart

Id like to call e.g. Text widget and autofill with all properties that I can change. Seems to me, that works only with required parameters, but how can I achieve this with all?

instead of autocomplete Text widget like this `Text(data);` I would expect

```
 Text(String data, 
              {Key? key, 
              TextStyle? style, 
              StrutStyle? strutStyle, 
              TextAlign? textAlign, 
              TextDirection? textDirection,
              Locale? locale, 
              bool? softWrap,
              TextOverflow? overflow, 
              double? textScaleFactor, 
              int? maxLines, 
              String? semanticsLabel, 
              TextWidthBasis? textWidthBasis, 
              TextHeightBehavior? textHeightBehavior})
```

Comment: Can you give an example what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "autofill with all properties that I can change"?